# How to extract some value from character column in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas

I have table in SAS like below:

data type:

- ID - numeric
- TYPE - character

  | ID | TYPE |
  | --- | --- |
  | 111 | {"Top":10} |
  | 222 | {"abC":"false","Top":111, "aa":5} |
  | 333 | {"Top":15.2} |
  | ... | ... |

And I need to create new column "COL1" base on column "TYPE" where I need to extract value which is after character "Top":

So I need something like below:

```
ID  | TYPE                              | COL1
--- |-----------------------------------|------
111 | {"Top":10}                        | 10
222 | {"abC":"false","Top":111, "aa":5} | 111
333 | {"Top":15.2}                      | 15.2
... | ...                               | ...
```

How can I do that in PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide ?

Comment: Why SQL? Why not just normal SAS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use the following

```
data want;
   set have;
   length col1 $50.;
   col1 = strip(scan(tranwrd(type,'"Top":','|'),2,'|},'));
run;
```

- Use the [`tranwrd()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p0pgemqcslm9uen1tvr5gcrusgrw.htm) function to replace all occurrences of `"Top":` in `type` by a vertical bar `|`.
- Use the [`scan()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_006/lefunctionsref/p0jshdjy2z9zdzn1h7k90u99lyq6.htm) function to extract the substring between the vertical bar `|` and the closing bracket `}` or comma `,`.

```
 id                    type                    col1
 111     {"Top":10}                              10
 222     {"abC":"false","Top":111,"aa":5}       111
 333     {"Top":15.2}                          15.2
```

Comment: Kermit, unfortunately it does not work, it creates 2 columns: col1 and type and both have null values, do you have any other idea maybe ?:)

Comment: excuse me Kermit, my failure, everything works gresat! thank you i gave best answer :)

Answer (score 2):

A regex-based solution:

```
data want;
    set have;

    /* Create a regular expression ID */
    regexid = prxparse('/(?<="Top":)(\d+)/');

    /* Find the position and length of the match */
    call prxsubstr(regexid, type, pos, len);

    /* Extract the match and convert it to a number */
    COL1 = input(substr(type, pos, len), 8.);
run;
```

You can test this out here:
https://regex101.com/r/0RDsCJ/1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your TYPE variable has JSON strings.  If the strings are as simple as your example you can just use nested SCAN() function calls to tease out the values.

So first let's convert your data listing into actual data.

```
data have;
  input ID TYPE $50.;
cards4;
111 {"Top":10}
222 {"abC":"false","Top":111, "aa":5}
333 {"Top":15.2}
;;;;
```

Now let's process the JSON text to pull out the name:value pairs. And when the name is `Top` let's convert the value into a number.

```
data want;
  set have;
  do index=1 to countw(type,'{,}','q');
     pair = scan(type,index,'{,}','q');
     name = dequote(scan(pair,1,':','q'));
     value = dequote(scan(pair,2,':','q'));
     if name='Top' then number=input(value,32.);
  end;
  drop index pair name value;
run;
```

Note that if Top appears multiple times in your JSON text the last value seen will be used.

Results:

```
OBS     ID    TYPE                                 number

 1     111    {"Top":10}                             10.0
 2     222    {"abC":"false","Top":111, "aa":5}     111.0
 3     333    {"Top":15.2}                           15.2
```